# Authentication to open .cache in the same user profile

Tags: permissions

I was running some files in Ubuntu 20.04 (focal). During that time, I have come across an error 13: Permission denied. So I give some files permission with mode 777. But after that I come across other problem which is when I opened .cache folder in home directory, it shows a window of authentication. How to get rid of this?

Can I change the permission of files as it was by reverting system in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance